# "error: unknown filesystem" after installing with failed update-grub on UEFI

Tags: debian, uefi, debian-installer

I tried installing Debian 8.7 on my Lenovo FLEX laptop. I downloaded the Netinstall from Debian's website and wrote the ISO file to a USB stick.

When I ran through the install process, it gave an error when it came to updating and installing GRUB. I forget the exact wording, but it was an error with `update-grub`. I continued installing despite the error.

If I try booting into Debian, I get a black screen with this error and command line...

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

[Here are images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpw4u.jpg) of the error, along with my BIOS's security and boot settings.

How do I install and boot Debian correctly with UEFI? (I also do not know much about UEFI vs Legacy booting).

Comment: To allow the grub installation on gpt disk , you should have a `bios-boot` partition (size=1M). You can create it manually . Some linux distro will create it automatically.

Comment: Boot-mode is UEFI disable fastboot, in Uefi-menu. And secure boot.

Comment: @Bahamut When I disable fastboot and enable secure boot, I get the error `debian has been blocked by the current security policy.`

Comment: you should not enable secure boot but disable.

Comment: @Bahamut Disabled it. Still getting the error and command prompt I described in my question.

Comment: Let us chitchat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56525/bahamut-username